# Is it possible to connect math with linguistics for a thesis?

Tags: mathematical-physics, education, math-history

I want to write my thesis next year and I really would like (if possible) to connect it, preferably with linguistics, neuroscience or philosophy.
I know from other students, who already have written their thesis, that it's possible to connect theses with physics, computer science or economics.

Could anyone give an advice ? Is it possible ? If possible which prof should I ask ? One of the area of numerics or algebra ?

Comment: [mathematical/computational linguistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computational_linguistics)?

Comment: Since you mention philosophy, and even if this is out of the scope of your thesis, you may be interested in some somewhat parallel topics on philosophy of language : See Kripke, Tarski or Wittgenstein... even Lacan at some extent.

Comment: See e.g. [Mathematical Linguistics](https://www.springer.com/it/book/9781846289859?utm_medium=affiliate&utm_source=commission_junction&utm_campaign=3_nsn6445_product_PID8992206&utm_content=it_09252018#otherversion=9781846289866) and [abstract](https://www.kornai.com/MatLing/matling3.pdf)

Comment: Look up Matilde marcolli